# htaccess 301 redirects by adding query parameter to the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do 301 redirect from the below URL

```
www.example.com/categories/Writing-Translation
```

to

```
www.example.com/categories/Writing-Translation-jobs
```

However, it is always redirecting a page with the following url

```
www.example.com/categories/categories/Writing-Translation-jobs?cid=Writing-Translation
```

This is the htaccess code used for redirection

## 301 Redirect

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cid=Writing-Translation$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^categories/Writing-Translation$ https://www.example.com/categories/Writing-Translation-jobs [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: And now you know why using 301 redirects is almost always the wrong answer to any problem. Every time you try to amend the rule, it will have no impact on what is happening at the browser - because your browser caches 301 redirects **indefinitely**. Leaving aside the question of whether this should *ultimately* be implemented as a permanent redirect, until you have a thouroughly tested solution (including a proper understanding of POST vs GET) you should be using one of the temporary redirect codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with the following rule by adding "/?" in the beginning:

> RewriteRule
>   ^/?categories/Writing-Translation$   https://www.example.com/categories/Writing-Translation-jobs
>   [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

You may use this rule as your **topmost rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cid=Writing-Translation$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^categories/Writing-Translation$ /categories/Writing-Translation-jobs? [R=301,NC,L]
```

`?` at the end of target URI will strip off existing query string. Make sure to test it in a new browser.